# Spring jdbcTemplate queryForObject cannot get right result

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I use jdbcTemplate like below:

```
Object[] params = new Object[] {
                vendInvPoLinItmVO.getVendInvNbr().trim(),
                // vendInvPoLinItmVO.getVendId(),
                // vendInvPoLinItmVO.getVendOrdHdrId(),
                vendInvPoLinItmVO.getScnCdMatTypCd().trim(),
                vendInvPoLinItmVO.getVendProdScnCd()
        };

count = this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(this.sqlCheckLiExist, params, Integer.class);
```

queryForObject () always gets count = 0, although there are one or more object(s) in database (I have already checked)

But I pass params with 1 or 2 element like this:

```
         Object[] params = new Object[] {
                vendInvPoLinItmVO.getVendInvNbr().trim(),
                vendInvPoLinItmVO.getVendProdScnCd()
        };
```

I get right result.

Here is my sql:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DSV.VEND_INV_PO_LIN_ITM WHERE UPPER (VEND_INV_NBR) = UPPER(?) AND SCN_CD_MAT_TYP_CD = ? AND VEND_PROD_SCN_CD = ?
```

with three params

The function queryForObject() limit the number of args?

How can I get right result with five args using queryForObject() or have any another solution?

Comment: It's impossible to help you without knowing the value of `this.sqlCheckLiExist`

Comment: Sorry!
My query is: 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DSV.VEND_INV_PO_LIN_ITM WHERE UPPER (VEND_INV_NBR) = UPPER(?) AND SCN_CD_MAT_TYP_CD = ? AND VEND_PROD_SCN_CD = ?

Comment: Are you sure if the query returns values, queryForObject() can process more than 5 query params

Comment: I have already checked query with 5 params, it gives count() = 1, but queryForObject() give 0. I am sure params are correct